# Binary operation with byte wont be executed because "Integer cant be converted to Byte"

Tags: vb.net

So I have this code snippet:

```vb
Private Sub Foo
    ' Get Byte()
    Dim Message As Byte() = Messages(0) ' Messages is a List<Byte()>
    ' Perform action on byte
    Dim h As Byte = DirectCast((Message(2) And &HF), Byte)
End Sub
```

Now I get the error "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Byte'" at `(Message(2) And &HF)`.

I know that `&HF` is an `Integer`, but how am I supposed to do binary operations on a `Byte` other than this way? I need the lower nibble of that byte.

Can someone please explain why this is the case? This should work, at least it does in C#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to perform a bitwise operation on two `Bytes` then you actually need two `Bytes`. Whole number literals are ALWAYS `Integers` by default, not `Bytes`. If you want a type other than `Integer` then you have to specify that. For some types, there are suffixes you can use, e.g. `L` for `Long`. There is no suffix for `Byte`, so you have to convert, e.g.

```vb
Dim h = Message(2) And CByte(&HF)
```

There's no need for the `DirectCast` because the result of `Anding` two `Bytes` together is a `Byte`. You can if you want but there's also no need to specify the type of the variable because it will be inferred to be `Byte` because that's the type of the initialising expression.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know that. I C# its all a bit clearer to me.